# Disable particular rows of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to "grey out" particular rows of a JTable so that they may not be selected by any means. The other rows should still be selectable. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: *"I would like to "grey out" particular rows of a JTable so that they may not be selected by any means"* What feature does this provide to the user?  What is in the selectable rows that makes sense to select them?  What is in the unselectable rows that makes them needed to be seen, but never selected?  It is likely you are approaching this the wrong way, and if you can achieve the effect, it will make for a confusing & frustrating GUI for the end user.

Comment: Users select items from one table and press a button to add them to another table. They want them to be visible in the first table but not able to be added to the second table again. I could disable the "add" button for entries in the second table, but the users have requested this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can either override `JTable.changeSelection()` to deselect the offending row whenever it's selected, or provide your table with a custom `ListSelectionModel` where you override `setSelectionInterval()`, `addSelectionInterval()`, etc. to prevent the row from being selected in the first place.

Comment: please to read my comment in the answer by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a custom TableCellRenderer, one that will display "disabled" information greyed out. Read the [Swing Table Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more on how to create these renderers, especially the section, Concepts: Editors and Renderers.

Comment: will that stop users from being able to select the row?  I thought that would just draw a row as if it's always disabled.  No idea if that's sufficient for the OP's purposes though.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified. I have read this tutorial and I'm trying to work with the TableCellRenderer, but I have no idea how to make it disable a particular row, and I can't find any docs that help here.

Comment: @Earl: to disable the row from editing, you would set it's editable property to false.

Comment: I'm not concerned with setting them to be editable, I want to set them to be unselectable. None of the cells are editable as it is.

Comment: my question is for why reason(s), you have to overide and to consume() all mouse, keyboard and ListSelection events, with to test if row is first or last, and moving with selections programatically, the same things with events implemented in the TableModel

Comment: +1 I think @orzechowskid is right about the `ListSelectionModel`, but a suitable renderer could help the user orient to the non-standard UI. In effect, you need both.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary `TableModel` which has only the rows that you want to select. After the selection made and when you want to revert, change back to original `TableModel`