# java swing - disable a particular row in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an instance of `JTable` in my java swing application. I want to disable some rows in the table based on conditions. In fact, I want some rows can not be selected when user tries to select them. Also their color should be gray. I found some similar question in stackoverflow, but none of them has a good answer. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319404/disable-particular-rows-of-a-jtable). Can anyone help me to implements this feature in the jtable?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: Sounds like you need a custom `ListSelectionModel`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092695/disable-particular-row-in-jtable-using-data-from-database.